# UNIX file metadata: Portable parsable solution (e.g. POSIX / ubiquitous)

Tags: bash, parsing, sh, ls, stat

I was writing a shell script, and was flabbergasted that I couldn't find a portable cross-platform method to get basic file metadata, like: type, modification time, permissions, paths for links, etc.  Basically, the same thing that `ls` outputs, but in a friendly parsable manner.

Reference this post for information about why you shouldn't parse `ls`:
[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129120/464414)

Everybody seems to say to use `stat` or `find` to accomplish a similar end-result, but again, I was flabbergasted to find that on my two computers (one Ubuntu 18.04, one MacOS X Catalina), I couldn't come up with any common syntax that worked on both systems.  I believe that both of these utilities are GNU extensions. Reference this post: [How can I get the size of a file in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16645/464414)

For `stat`, Ubuntu uses `--printf=FORMAT` to specify fields.  In MacOS X (BSD-based), the syntax is `-f format`.  The names and ordering of the fields are also different, making parsing with RegEx not practical.

For `find`, Ubuntu has an "action" field available for `-printf format`.  MacOS X simply doesn't have this option or anything comparable that I'm aware of.

**So my question is:
If `ls`, `stat`, and `find` don't provide a portable solution to get parsable file metadata, how do I do it?  Just suck it up and parse ls???**  This seems so basic that I can't believe there isn't something that works cross-platform... It doesn't have to be POSIX per-se, just something that's basically ubiquitous for 'Nix OS'es.

I've found two somewhat junky solutions so far, but I'll note them for reference... :

1. Use `rsync` as a helper tool, and use its `--out-format` flag.  Use the `--dry-run` option so it doesn't actually do any file transferring.  I tried this on both my Mac and Linux boxes, and it seemed to work, but it's pretty slow/grimy, and I don't know if `rsync` is considered ubiquitous or not.  I found this from some StackOverflow post that I forgot to bookmark. ;-)
2. Use `tar` as a helper tool (I know that `pax` is the new POSIX standard, but it wasn't on my Ubuntu box), pipe the output, and parse its headers only.  Discard the rest (e.g. pipe it to `/dev/null`).  I found this idea on this post: [Getting file modification time in POSIX shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561933/464414).  So... I definitely consider the `tar` utility ubiquitous enough (it used to be part of POSIX).  And the headers are great for parsing.  I'm a little concerned though that it might be reading more file content than I want it to, though.

I tested both methods with a directory containing some huge files (e.g. 70GB) and the `tar` method definitely isn't reading the whole files, though you can slightly notice that it's slower than `ls` / `stat` / `find`.  And the code takes a bit of fancy footwork...

To re-iterate my question, is there a less-grimy way to get file metadata in a portable way, that at least works on OSX and Ubuntu and most 'Nix'es?

---

REFERENCE MATERIAL - INTERESTED READERS ONLY

Here are code snippets for Method 1 and Method 2 above.  I started with the reference posts, and took it to the next step.  For demonstration purposes, the code I'm posting below uses the output of each method to print a directory listing that looks like `ls`.  Just for a demo...

Both methods: Grimy, grimy

Method 1 (`rsync`):

```
ALT_STAT() {
    ALT_STAT_NAME="${1}"
    set -- $(rsync --dry-run --dirs --ignore-times --links --specials --out-format='%i %B %l %U %G' "${1}" "${1}")
    ALT_STAT_TYPE="${1:1:1}"
    ALT_STAT_PERMS="${2}"
    ALT_STAT_EXEC="$(echo "${2}" | sed -n $'/[xt]/i\\\nexe')"
    ALT_STAT_LABEL="$(echo $'freg\nddir\nLlnk\nDdev\nSspe' | sed -n '/^${ALT_STAT_TYPE}/s/^.//p')"
    [ "${ALT_STAT_LABEL}"="reg" -a "${ALT_STAT_EXEC}"="exe" ] && ALT_STAT_LABEL="exe"
    ALT_STAT_SIZE="${3}"
    ALT_STAT_USER="$(id -un ${4})"
    ALT_STAT_GROUP="${5}"
    ALT_STAT_LINK=$(readlink "${ALT_STAT_NAME}")
    [ "${ALT_STAT_LINK}" -a "${ALT_STAT_LINK:1:1}" != "/" ] && ALT_STAT_LINK="$(PATH="$(pwd):${PATH}" which ${ALT_STAT_LINK})"
    ALT_STAT_MTIME=$(date -r "${ALT_STAT_LINK:-${ALT_STAT_NAME}}" +%s)
    [ "${ALT_STAT_LINK}" ] && ALT_STAT_LINK="--> ${ALT_STAT_LINK}"
}

ALT_LS() {
    for f in *; do
        ALT_STAT "${f}"
        printf "%3.3s | %9.9s | %12.12s | %10.10s | %9.9s | %50.50s | %s\n" \
        "${ALT_STAT_LABEL}" "${ALT_STAT_PERMS}" "${ALT_STAT_USER}" "${ALT_STAT_GROUP}"\
        "${ALT_STAT_SIZE}" "${ALT_STAT_NAME} ${ALT_STAT_LINK}" $(date -r "${ALT_STAT_MTIME}" +%D_%T)
    done
}
```

Method 2 (`tar`):

```
cat > fileMetadata.sh <<\ENDSCRIPT
#!/bin/bash

readTarHeader() {
    read -n 100; name="${REPLY}"
    read -n 8; mode="${REPLY}"
    read -n 8; uid=$((8#${REPLY}))
    read -n 8; gid=$((8#${REPLY}))
    read -n 12; size=$((8#${REPLY}))
    read -n 12; mtime=$((8#${REPLY}))
    read -n 8; checksum=$((8#${REPLY}))
    read -n 1; typeflag="${REPLY}"
    read -n 100; linkname="${REPLY}"
    read -n 6; magic="${REPLY}"
    read -n 2; version="${REPLY}"
    read -n 32; uname="${REPLY}"
    read -n 32; gname="${REPLY}"
    read -n 8; devmajor="${REPLY}"
    read -n 8; devminor="${REPLY}"
    read -n 155; prefix="${REPLY}"
    read -n 12; # Padding

    # Flush buffers (tested on a 78GB file; it was so fast that it can't be reading it)
    cat > /dev/null
}

writeBackHeaders() {
    printf "%6.6s | %1.1s | %16.16s | %8.8s | %9.9s | %19.19s | %10.10s | %35.35s" \
        "${mode}" "${typeflag}" "${uname}" "${gname}" "${size}" $(date -r "${mtime}" +%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M%:%s) "${prefix}" "${name} ${linkname}"
    echo
}

printMetaData() {
    for file in "${@}"; do
        tar --use-compress-program="${0} -t" -c "${file}" | cat 
    done
}

[ "${1}" = "-t" ] && { readTarHeader; writeBackHeaders; exit 0; }

[ "${1}" = "-p" ] || exit -1

[ -d ${2} ] && printMetaData "${2}"* || printMetaData "${2}"

ENDSCRIPT
```

Usage:

```
chmod 777 fileMetadata.sh
./fileMetadata.sh -p testDir2/
```

Comment: Related: [POSIX analog of coreutils “stat” command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27828585/3266847)

Comment: Yeah, the Perl solution in that one doesn't look too bad, though I haven't even checked yet to see if my machines both have it installed.  I might be a little less picky about "pure" POSIX than the OP in that thread (sounds like he didn't get the answer he was looking for)

Comment: "Ubuntu" is a weirdly specific platform to single out. Mainline Linux distributions, including Debian, on which Ubuntu is based, use GNU `coreutils`. There are some specialized distros with different userland utilities (which in the case of Busybox is Busybox itself).

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is currently a gap in what POSIX provides.

A common workaround is to write a simple script in another language to extract the information you need. While not strictly standard, modern scripting languages like Python and Perl are reasonably ubiquitous, and often provide sufficient additional value to make sense as an extra dependency even when you try to write otherwise portable scripts.

Both Python and Perl expose the underlying `stat` system call. Here are two simple examples.
Rather than providing an exhaustive example, I only demonstrate how to print the file size, and link to the documentation for more details.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    st = os.stat(filename)
    print(f"{st.st_size}\t{filename}")
```

For the documentation for Python's `os.stat` call, see
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html

(The use of `f"..."` strings requires Python >= 3.7.)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
for $file (@ARGV) {
    print(join("\t", (stat($file))[7], $file), "\n") 
}
```

For documentation of the Perl `stat` call, please see https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat

Both of these scripts can be refactored to one-liners; Perl lets you provide a script as a command-line argument with `-e`, while Python uses `-c` for this purpose.

Demo: https://ideone.com/vlfQu8

In really desperate situations, you'd have to write and compile a small utility in C or Rust etc. This will be quite a bit more verbose than either of the above alternatives, but reduce your attack surface (provided you have the competence to write secure code in a more low-level language), but obviously then not be portable between different hardware architectures.

These examples are also a compromise between human-friendly and properly unambiguous computer-readable output. If you need to cope with file names which could contain newlines, perhaps make the output null-delimited (which is problematic for POSIX shell utilities; though the next release of 1003.2 should allegedly finally bring some relief in this area) or wrap it in a computer-readable format like JSON (where again POSIX does not provide robust standard tooling, but third-party tools like `jq` are available for free, and reasonably commonly installable via trusted sources etc). Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 (not just about Bash).

For file size in particular, [How to compare folders size in bash/sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107010/how-to-compare-folders-size-in-bash-sh) (approximately) suggests

```
size=$(du -s --bytes filename | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

but, alas, `--bytes` is not in POSIX, either (nor on e.g. MacOS).

Comment: https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=243#c6110 was marked as accepted in 2023, but as of this writing, the latest version of the standard is still the one from 2017.