# How to compare folders size in bash/sh?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am building a simple caching script in bash.

Let us assume we have the folders

- `source`
- `dest`

I want to write a if condition and check if the total size of source matches the total size of dest (by total size I mean it includes also the subfolders subfiles recursively everything), then do some action.

The script will look something like:

```
sourceSizeInBytes=2; // dont know how to get only total in bytes
destSizeInBytes=2; // dont know how to get only total in bytes

if [ $sourceSizeInBytes -eq $destSizeInBytes ]
then
   echo "Both folders have equal size. I will do something";
else
  echo "folders are not of the same size";
fi
```

du -sch gives not just a number but more information.

How can I write such a condition in one reliable way ?

Comment: sh, or bash? They're not the same -- best to tag only for one or the other so you get answers compatible with the shell you're actually using. (Even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash` on your OS, it turns off some features for better compatibility when called under the `sh` name).

Comment: How should size be calculated for files that have multiple hardlinks? Do you care about filesize, or the diskspace actually used? (consider output of GNU find here: `echo hello >a; find a -printf '%s bytes / %k kilobytes'`)  What about sparse files? What if both directories report the same size but contain different files?

Comment: ignoring timestamps, hardlinks, etc, but requiring all files exist in both and have same size (but maybe not same content): `rsync -n -ir --size-only source/ dest/ | grep -q . && echo different || echo same`

Comment: For the size of a certain file, are you interested in the number of bytes which make up this file, or the disk space occupied by the file?

Comment: @user1934428 Either is fine as long as I can make an accurate comparison between two folders. I have interest only in checking if they are of same size or not in 100% accurate way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Charles Duffy in the comments, if you're using `GNU bash`, below code is more suitable:

```
read sourceSizeInBytes _ < <(du -s --bytes source) 
read destSizeInBytes _ < <(du -s --bytes dest) 
   
if (( sourceSizeInBytes == destSizeInBytes ))
then
   echo "Both folders have equal size. I will do something"
else
  echo "folders are not of the same size"
fi
```

Comment: If using bash-only syntax (which you already  are in `[[`), one might consider `read sourceSizeInBytes _ < <(du -sb source)` to avoid needing awk. Likewise, `if (( a == b ))` is just as bash-only as `if [[ $a -eq b ]]` but easier to read.

Comment: BTW, `du -b` historically was 512-byte **blocks**, not bytes, and [POSIX doesn't specify its meaning](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) so an implementation can do either of the two (or just not support any `-b` flag at all, which is f/e what MacOS does). If you want to write code that only works on GNU, might be better to use `--bytes` so it fails outright rather than returning wrong results on an OS where `-b` has a different meaning.

Comment: Thanks This does not work on Mac `--bytes not recognised` but I will accept this solution if no other one comes later.